# Choose which duplicate to take in a SQL view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, duplicates

I'm trying to solve a SQL problem for me which is basically to chose from two duplicate the one I want from another column.

I have three columns: code, value and description:

```
code | value | description
23   | 1     | hello
23   | 2     | goodbye
```

Here there is a duplicate on the code column. But in my view I only want the line with the highest value so the second line.

I tried to use the `MAX()` on the value column but I don't know how to apply it on code that are in the table more than one time.

I also found this on internet:

```
SELECT l.* 
FROM livre l 
INNER JOIN ( 
   SELECT categorie, MAX(date) AS maxDate 
   FROM livre 
   GROUP BY categorie 
) groupel ON l.categorie = groupel.categorie AND l.date = groupel.maxDate
```

But I don't understand the thing with the l.

Can you help me with this or is there a better way to do this extraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a correlated subquery is a simple and usually highly-performance solution:

```
select l.*
from livre l
where l.value = (select max(l2.value)
                 from livre l2
                 where l2.code = l.code
                );
```

For performance, you want an index on `livree(code, value)`.

Comment: Work perfectly for my case and simple to understand thx!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `row_number()` window function to select the correct row.

```
declare @Livre table (Code int, [Value] int, [Description] varchar(12));

insert into @Livre (Code, [Value], [Description])
values (23,1,'Hello'),(23,2,'Goodbye');

with cte as (
    select Code, [Value], [Description]
        , row_number() over (partition by Code order by [Value] desc) rn
    from @Livre
)
select Code, [Value], [Description]
from cte 
where rn = 1;
```

Returns:

```
Code    Value   Description
23      2       Goodbye
```

Answer (score 1):

In that script you found on the internet, the 'l' is an alias given to the (orignal) table.
This is then joined to a subquery which returns the MAX date of that same table. The results of the subquery are akin to being a separate table, and have been given the alias 'groupel'.

By using an INNER JOIN and selecting l.*, this returns all records from the original table where the subquery identifies that as being the MAX date for the given category.

For your example table, something like this is equivalent:

```
SELECT orig.* 
FROM Table orig 
INNER JOIN ( 
   SELECT code, MAX(Value) AS MaxValue 
   FROM Table 
   GROUP BY code 
) MAX ON orig.code = MAX.code AND orig.value = MAX.MaxValue
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach, without the use of a `CTE`. You can `JOIN` the table to itself -

```
CREATE TABLE Livre (
  [Code] int, 
  [Value] int, 
  [Description] varchar(25)
)

INSERT INTO Livre ([Code], [Value], [Description]) VALUES (23,1,'Hello')
INSERT INTO Livre ([Code], [Value], [Description]) VALUES (23,2,'Goodbye')

SELECT l2.[Code], l2.[Value], l2.[Description]
FROM Livre l1
JOIN Livre l2
ON l2.code = l1.code
AND l2.[Value] > l1.[Value]
```

Output -

```
Code     Value     Description
23       2         Goodbye
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6af7a3/1)

Comment: Break if there are more than 2 duplicate rows though. And performs worse.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT      *
FROM        Livre l1
WHERE       EXISTS(
  SELECT      MAX(Value) 
  FROM        Livre l2 
  WHERE       l1.Code = l2.Code 
  HAVING      L1.Value = MAX(VALUE)
)
```

Comment: If you indent your code with 4 spaces or surround it with backticks (`) it will show up so code. This makes it easier to read!